# how to chain function return codes in bash script

Tags: bash

following code gives error "foo:return: too many arguments"

```
f123() { echo $1; return 1; }
f124() { echo $1; return 1; }
foo() {
    return f123 "hello" && f124 "world"
}
foo
```

requirement is:

- I want foo to execute f124 only if f123 returns non-zero return value
- I want foo to return the return value of the last command that was successfully executed with non-zero return code

How do I do this in bash?

Comment: Ok. But still, how I do effective chaining

Comment: do a test with `false ; foo $?` ? Good luck.

Comment: Strike that trailing `$?` (now that I understand your code better). Good luck.

Comment: foo function does not take any arguments. I see that you are passing $? to foo. What is it doing? Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Can you tell me how to avoid the error message "foo:return: too many arguments" ?

Comment: I think you want `return $(f123 "hello") && $(f124 "world")` ? ALSO add `set -vx` at the top of each function so you can follow the flow of what gets executed. Can't help with error msg now. Going to lunch. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163281/discussion-between-user855-and-shellter).

Comment: I agree with and have upvoted chepner's answer. If this really doesn't solve your problem for reasons/restraints not in your original Q, then maybe you need to post a new Q that better explains your issues? Going out with my dog for a while. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `return` here at all; the exit status of the function is the exit status of the last command executed. `return` is only need to return an explicit exit status.

```
foo() {
    f123 "hello" && f124 "world"
}
```

If `f123` fails (has a non-zero exit status), `f124` does not execute and the exit status of `f123` is used as the exit status of `foo`. If `f123` succeeds, then `f124` *does* execute, and its exit status (zero or not) is used as the exit status of `foo`.

(If you really want `f124` to execute when `f123` fails, then use `||` instead of `&&`.)

Comment: Thanks.

is the exit status of the function same as the return value of the function if one is provided?

Comment: Functions don't have return values in shell. They have exit statuses, and they can write to standard output, but they don't return values.

Answer (score -1):

Bash returns 0 on success but you are forcing to return 1 in your functions. Now, double ampersand operator && means: execute if previous command was successful, i.e. it returned 0. You will have to do it manually if you insist on return values greater than 0

```
f123() { echo $1; return 1; }
f124() { echo $1; return 1; }
foo() {
    f123 "hello"
    r1=$?
    if [ "$r1" -gt 0 ] ; then
        f124 "world"
        r2=$?
        if [ "$r2" -gt 0 ]; then
            r1=$r2
        fi
    fi
    return $r1
}
```

Comment: What's the return value from foo()?

Comment: @chepner I disagree, it replies the answer as requested. || follows the bash logic where 0 is success. Also the code is verbose but correct.